# Using a 'foreach' loop with stringArray in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am writing a program which should display the items from an array in a foreach loop.

I wanted to change the elements of the array by adding a string "sad" to each element, but when run the program the array stays the same.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] stringArray = {"hey", "Tom"};

            for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.Length; i++ )
            {
                stringArray[i] += "  dad";
                Console.WriteLine(stringArray[i]);
            }

            Array.Resize(ref stringArray, stringArray.Length + 1);

            // Add bob to the last element of the array
            stringArray[stringArray.Length - 1] =" bob";

            foreach (string s in stringArray)
            {
                string b = s + "sad";
                Console.WriteLine(s);
                //Console.WriteLine(stringArray);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should change string b = s + "sad"; to  string s += "sad";

Comment: possible typo `Console.WriteLine(b);` instead of `Console.WriteLine(s);`

Answer (score 14):

```
        foreach (string s in stringArray)
        {   
            string b = s + "sad";
            // ...
        }
```

Here you are creating a new string, completely unrelated to the string in the string-array. You haven't changed the old string (you can't; strings are immutable). You then simply drop this new longer string on the floor - you aren't updating the array etc.

Try instead something like:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < stringArray.Length ; i++)
{
    stringArray[i] = stringArray[i] + "sad";
}
```

This *replaces* every item in the array with a new string. Note that you can't update a list/collection/array etc while iterating with `foreach` - that can break the iterator. Hence the `for` loop instead.

Answer (score 12):

Apart from what Chris said, you could simply use LINQ to achieve what you want:

```
string[] newStringArray = stringArray
    .Select(s => s + "sad")
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
string b = s + "sad";

Console.WriteLine(s);

//Console.WriteLine(stringArray);
```

At no point in your code do you alter values in the array. You create a new `string` from each value in the array, concatenated with the string `"sad"`.

**Solution**

You can not alter a `for-each` variable. You'll get a message like:

> Cannot assign to 's' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'.

Instead, settle for a simple `for` loop.

```
for(int x = 0; x < stringArray.length; x++)
{
     stringArray[x] = stringArray[x] + "sad";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this part of the code:

```
string b = s + "sad";
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

You are concatenating the string in `s` with the string `"sad"`, and storing in the variable `b`. Then you display the content of the variable `s`. If you would display the content of the variable `b` isntead, there would be a `sad` at the end of each string.